# Code will execute both if and else statements. Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have an array called used.I have a function which add a code in the array but checks if the code has been added again.If it has been added it has to say "False" else True
the problem is that it will say both false and true.
Here is my code:

```
   var used=[];//use that to check if the user has added the code to favourites again

var x='',y='',blur='',r="",g="",b="",op="",color="rgb(0,0,0)",shadow=''; //create the variables that will be used 
function update(){
    x=$("#x").val();
    y=$("#y").val();
    op=$("#o").val();
    r=$("#red").val();
    g=$("#green").val();
    b=$("#blue").val();
    blur=$("#blur").val();
    shadow = x+"px "+y+"px ";


}
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#addC").click(function(){
  if(used.indexOf(shadow) != -1){
    alert("false");
  }
  else{
    used.push(shadow);
    alert("True");

  }
 });
   $('.shadow-slider').change(function(){

    update();

     if (op != 1){
    if(op.length > 3){op=op.substring(0, 3);}
    color="rgba("+r+","+g+","+b+","+op+")";
   }
   else{
    color="rgb("+r+","+g+","+b+")";
   }
   if (blur != 0){shadow += blur+"px ";}
   shadow += color;
   $('#object').css("text-shadow",shadow);
   $('#code-output').html("text-shadow:"+shadow+";");

   });



});
```

Shadow is a global variable which  changes depending on some sliders of my page.Any ideas?

Comment: Your click event handler is being triggered twice.

Comment: where is it triggered twice.I cn't see anything

Answer (score 4):

I am thinking you have bound the click handler twice, so the first time it is not found and you get the second case (*and add it*) but the second time it is found (*added the first time*) and shows the first case.